# Removing /public from URL in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes

Even though there are hundreds similar questions out there, but none is actually solving my problem.
I have setup a Laravel 7.14.1 application, and I uploaded it to a shared host.

To make it work on shared host, I did the following steps:

1- Renamed server.php to index.php

2- Moved .htaccess to root

3- In .htaccess I put the following rules

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

4- Created a test route like follows:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'HI';
});
```

Now when I visit `domain.com/test` it gives me 404 error
But when I visit `doamin.com/public/test` it works

How can I remove the /public part from my url?

Comment: you have to make sure the "public" folder is the home directory. if you are using lamp or xxamp, or wamp.

Comment: It's a shared host, how can I do that?

Comment: in that case,you have to upload your laravel app above your shared hosting public_html folder and the contains of public folder stays goes to public_html

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that.I have specific structure.

Comment: first upload your project on main root  then  move  public folder to public_html.. and change the service provider register method to read data from public_html

Comment: Can any one explain further why this is good, in a separate answer? Thanks!

Comment: ask your system maintainer to set the DocumentRoot to the public folder.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to resolve this.

1. First, upload the contents of public folder on your local machine to public_html on web server.
2. upload every other files and folders outside public_html.
3. and done, no configuration files update necessary.

Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

The following are the steps you can follow to host your laravel application on shared hosting(cpanel)

**1 Step:** Login to your shared hosting account (cpanel) dashboard then find File Manager icon then click it

[image]

[image]

Click **public_html** , actually this is where normally we upload our web application contents, so upload your laravel project here but we need to do extract work to make our project running please proceed with following steps

**2. Step:**  Organize your laravel project

[image]

Create folder in main root of your laravel project any name will fit, mine i call it **system** as shown below
[image]

Then i move all the other folders except public to this new created folder.

[image]

Here you will result into

[image]

Takes all your **public** content outside the main root as shown below

[image]

Then here what will result

[image]

You can remove public folder or leave it

**3 Step:**  Edit index.php file found in your main root

[image]

We need to edit line code number 22 and 36 to the following as shown below

NB: The secret behind is to tell our index.php file where it can find those two files

You can test your project by navigating to your domain.

[image]

**4. Step** : Conclusion,

There is interesting package that sum up all what we did as laravel package please have a look, [click here](https://github.com/Biggo6/cpanel)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and safest solution for shared hostings:

1. Go to your Laravel/Lumen root path from SSH
2. Run `mv .htaccess .htaccess-BACKUP` to backup your current `.htaccess`
3. Run `cp public/index.php ./ && cp public/.htaccess ./`
4. Enjoy :)

NOTE: If you don't have SSH access, you can do exactly the same thing manually from cPanel > File Manager