# Correct .htaccess exists in the server but not redirected and excuted PHP code in Laravel with Apache2

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

Everyone.
I am using the correct a .htaccess file and put it into the Laravel directory and now my ubuntu server has the apache2 process. All is okay but not working correctly and executed the PHP code of my project. What is the solution？ I will attach my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Regards

Comment: You're not actually rewriting to a .php file that will be executed. e.g. `public/index.php` or `public/index.php/$1`

Comment: I have faced this issue before, please let me know if you find the solution, thank you

Comment: apokryfos, it isn't problem. I have written as you want, but it didn't work before.

Comment: Is the rewriting module loaded into the http server _at all_ ? How did you make sure it is?

Comment: What is the actual problem?  You are not using [the normal Laravel .htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess), so Laravel and PHP won't work, but when apokryfos pointed this out you said it isn't a problem.  I am not sure what the rewrite rules you *do* have will actually do - probably nothing?  What is the goal?  What *does* happen? What is your question?

Comment: Sounds to me like that lavavel based application is located in the "public" folder. So this rule set would supplement the laravel rules probably located inside that folder. But indeed this is unclear from the question. And if so these rules certainly will create a rewriting loop ...

Comment: I see, yes @arkascha I think you are right.  In which case the question is probably "how do I run Laravel from the root directory"?  I would first say don't do that - your `.env` file with all sensitive info will be potentially visible to the world.  `public/` is supposed to be your document root. If you're still going to do it, there are many examples here, eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/40756665, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39057011, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62467165 ...

Comment: Thank you for you guys support, I will check them.